# Cannot find libc6

Tags: 12.04, package-management, steam

When I open steam, it tells me that I need to download additional packages.

First it says: 
    Failed to fetch http://dep.playonlinux.com/dists/precise/Release
    Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release 
    file.

Then here are the packages it cannot locate:

```
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-quantal:i386
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal:i386
E: Unable to locate package libc6:i386
```

I used synaptic and it says that those packages are there but not the i386 versions.

I have tried the following code:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
```

And that doesnt work. I have been looking through various threads about this all night. Nothing seems to work.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: You are running 12.04? Some of the packages being searched for are for Quantal.... Installing for 12.04 should be a simple matter of `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`

Answer (score 0):

There are i386 libc packages at [https://launchpad.net] :)

[i386 libc package downloads](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/2.11.1-0ubuntu7/+build/1702390)

Comment: Hi Mr. Sam, I am real new to Ubuntu. I just download the eglibc-source_2.11.1-0ubuntu7_all.deb  and installed them. I still get the same error message.

Comment: Hi there, what exactly are you hearing back in errors, please copy the error data to you're question  and I'll try my very best to help to help you out. -it doesn't take long at all at the learning curve. : )

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on a 64-bit machine. You should do the following:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
```